# mongodb regex parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

Refer to the code below:

```
{$or: [
        {titleLong: { $regex: regExp } },
        {catalog: { $regex: regExp } },
        {catalogNbr: { $regex: regExp } }
      ]}
```

I am trying to find the documents whose fields match a certain regex expression. For example, there's this document.

```
{course: {titleLong: "Introduction to analysis of algorithms"},
         {catalog: "cs3333"},
         {catalogNbr: "3333"}}
```

and when the user types "intro algo" or "3333" or "cs3333" the document should be returned. I tried `/(intro|algo)/gi` but it doesn't work becaue it returns all documents that either have `intro` or `algo`. Also, the `g` options doesn't seem to work. I also found the following regex:

```
(?=.*\bintro\b)(?=.*\balgo\b).+
```

But this only finds documents that have words that are exactly like `intro` and misses `introduction`.

Comment: then remove the word boundaries. `(?=.*intro)(?=.*algo).+`

Comment: Remove the first `\b` to find entries with words starting with the values: `(?=.*\bintro)(?=.*\balgo).+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the word boundaries present inside the lookahead assertion so that it would do a partial match.

```
(?=.*intro)(?=.*algo).+
```

OR

```
(?=.*intro).*algo.*
```

And don't forget to turn on the case insensitive modifier `i`

Include the pattern to match `"3333"` or `"cs3333"` also.

```
(?=.*intro).*algo.*|^(?:cs)?3333$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCRE when you define `$regex`. You can return all entries starting with specific words, and use inline options like `(?i)` (case insensitive search). Here is an example:

```
 {titleLong: { { $regex: '(?i).*\bintro.*' } }
```

or entris containing "intro" in any position in the string:

```
 {titleLong: { { $regex: '(?i).*intro.*' } }
```